# Sequence numbers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that has a **seq** (sequence number field). I'd like it to be an invisible field, and for it to auto-increment, but be separate from the id.

On the index page, I'd like to be able to drag-and-drop the rows to re-sequence them, and the sequence should then go from 1 to the highest row.

What's the easy way to do this or can anyone suggest a tutorial I could follow?

Comment: What do you do if an entry is deleted - does it leave a hole in the sequence or get patched up?

Comment: Good question: I would want the sequence to be patched up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is for your records to be "sortable". Take a look at these plugins: [Active Record Sortables](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Sortables)

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402324/resetting-position-attribute-when-using-acts-as-list-gem-rails